# Upgrade Kernel to 3.8.0-35-generic fails to boot. Missing initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

When upgrading to the new kernel 3.8.0-35-generic (12.04 LTS) it doesn't create the initrd.img file and won't boot. I get a Kernel Panic because it's missing the img

I tried running

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 3.8.0-35-generic
```

but it does nothing. No image file is created

Comment: I couldn't get it to boot. I had to boot an older kernel and roll back. sudo apt-get remove 3.8.0-35-generic && sudo update-grub

Comment: Maybe /boot is out of free space?

Comment: Nope /boot partition has plenty of space.

Answer (score 0):

Boot an older kernel, then executed the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.8.0-35 linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.8.0-35 linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic
```

Comment: Using the first line purges just fine to the older kernel and I can boot again, but as soon as I install using the second line breaks it again. I even tried to install a much newer kernel sudo apt-get install linux-headers-3.11.0-17 linux-headers-3.11.0-17-generic linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic and it still doesn't create the initrd.img-3.11.0-17 file.