# Upgrade Kernel to 3.8.0-35-generic fails to boot. "Gave up waiting for root device"

Tags: 12.04, server, grub2, lts

The previous kernel 3.8.0-34 was fine, and is still fine when I choose "older kernels" from the GRUB screen at boot.

Note, this is a corporate system on VMware and using LVM as per defaults.

Have tried suggestions at [Upgrade Kernel to 3.8.0-35-generic fails to boot. Missing initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405958/upgrade-kernel-to-3-8-0-35-generic-fails-to-boot-missing-initrd-img-3-8-0-29-ge) but no joy with those.

Comment: The system has now auto-upgraded to 3.8.0-36-generic, and the problems *still* exists (I'd been hoping that it was a "oncer".

Answer (score 1):

The system has now auto-upgraded to 3.8.0-36-generic, and the problems *still* exists (I'd been hoping that it was a "oncer").

In practice I've "solved" this by pinning the -34 kernel, by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.8.0-35 linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.8.0-36 linux-headers-3.8.0-36-generic linux-image-3.8.0-36-generic
```

Then running:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And pinning the -34 kernel with:

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-headers-3.8.0-34
sudo apt-mark hold linux-headers-3.8.0-34-generic
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic
```

And checking this via:

```
dpkg -l | grep ^h
hi  linux-headers-3.8.0-34           3.8.0-34.49~precise1              Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.8.0
hi  linux-headers-3.8.0-34-generic   3.8.0-34.49~precise1              Linux kernel headers for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
hi  linux-image-3.8.0-34-generic     3.8.0-34.49~precise1              Linux kernel image for version 3.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```